# Suggested mandate of Wikivoyage links

Tags: discussion, hyperlinks

Since the community from [Wikitravel](http://wikitravel.org/) has mostly migrated to [Wikivoyage](http://www.wikivoyage.org/), I'm suggesting we mandate that if you see a new answer with a Wikitravel link in it, we alter it to the equivalent Wikivoyage link.

Thoughts, comments?

Comment: TIL that Wikivoyage exists. Why the fork?

Comment: @Gilles [Wikitravel vs Wikivoyage - what's going to be the difference?](http://meta.travel.stackexchange.com/q/881/2509)

Comment: What evidence do we have that it has mostly migrated, really?

Comment: @gerrit there are quite a few news articles around if you look.  They took the entire database. Sure some new stuff will be on wikitravel from casual editors, but for the most part, they've moved across to work on wikivoyage.  It's also been taken under the wikimedia foundation, which lends it more credence.

Comment: @MarkMayo I've seen the news articles about the administrators deciding to move, and that they took the database. I think currently, wikitravel is still much more known that wikivoyage, google points more to wikitravel, etc. What do real edit statistics for the past month look like, for example?

Comment: @Gilles More info here http://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Wikivoyage/Why

Comment: Of course Google points more to Wikitravel, there's so many links around the net that have built up over years that point to it. But it will decrease as Wikivoyage builds up more content, I'm sure.

Comment: The question is worth asking hence my upvote, but I feel that doing this would be too political really. I'm in favour of supporting Wikivoyage explicitly and in more ways, but this sounds more like proselytising - if people want to link to Wikitravel that's their business.

Answer (score 5):

I sincerely hope and expect that Wikivoyage will soon take over Wikitravel as the dominant user-contributed travel guide.

However, I think that for deciding whether to link to Wikivoyage or Wikitravel, we should decide on a *per-case basis* what article is better. Now I would suspect that in most cases, the Wikivoyage article is going to be better, in particular since the free license guarantees that any good material added to Wikitravel can be copied over to Wikivoyage. But before mandating this, I propose we collect some evidence that Wikivoyage really is better for the end user.

Comment: [Wikitravel stats](http://wikitravel.org/en/Special:Statistics) and [Wikivoyage stats](http://stats.wikimedia.org/wikivoyage/EN/Sitemap.htm) - if you'd like to peruse.  Already more articles on Wikivoyage.

Comment: Ok. I don't really oppose, am just a tad cautious because I suspect many of the active users on Travel SE are also among those moderators who migrated from Wikitravel to Wikivoyage. But I do acknowledge that there is neutral evidence as well, and I just realised that a lot of new user influx will probably come via Wikipedia.

Comment: For sure, good to be cautious!

Answer (score 4):

Systematically deleting links to one site and replacing them by links to another site would be a very tough measure.

If I post an answer, and I add a link to a site A, then I probably have a good reason to do so. I believe that this link conveys useful and relevant information. I would be irritated if this link was deleted and replaced by a link to a site B, just because of some "private" or "ideological" reasons.

If some users think that a link is not appropriate they can either add a comment and post an alternative, or downvote they answer if they don't agree. And in really severe cases the answer could be flagged for moderation.

Comment: I do agree, but it's also worth reminding ourselves that all Q's and A's are wikis open for all to edit to keep up-to-date and relevant and are not "owned" by their OP's. So if at some point the WikiTravel pages rot and the WikiVoyage pages soar then it could be a good thing... but yeah not at this point even though  I dislike WikiTravel (-;

Comment: Agreed. If pages rot, replace them by better references. But only then.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like a political move. I cannot support this.

And certain circumstances, it would not even make sense, like this user has already done here:

https://travel.stackexchange.com/posts/7995/revisions

It makes it sound like the edit in question was ripped off from Wikivoyage, whereas it was actually ripped off from Wikitravel, where the original edit was made (apparently by the same user?). There wasn't even an english language version of wikivoyage when that edit was made! Just confusing as all heckfire.

I say no.

Comment: Agreed. It should be the prerogative of the OP to choose whether to link to WT or WV, and they could change it themselves if they so choose. Exceptions should be made when the content from WT somehow gets missing (does that actually happens?) and only WV has relevant (at the time of edit) information.

Answer (score -1):

- WikiVoyage has far less spam.
- As an "open"-oriented community, I think we should support consensus-based WikiVoyage, and not dictatorial WikiTravel which sues editors.
- Case-by-case would be unnecessary overhead. Please show me ANY article that is better on WikiTravel than on WikiVoyage.
- WikiVoyage already has more edits, of better quality, and this trend won't reverse, so we are bound to migrate them all eventually.
- Advertising ruins the reading experience at WikiTravel, to the point that linking to it smells like touting. Let's send our readers to ad-free WikiVoyage, they will have a better time and trust our QA site more.

For these reasons, we should migrate links from WikiTravel to WikiVoyage.

Answer (score -2):

<sup>***Please keep this answer's score at -1 so that new answers are not eclipsed when sorting by votes.***</sup>

In order to make it easier to compare the quality of Wikitravel and Wikivoyage, and to edit links if warranted, here is a list of all the links to Wikitravel on the main site as of 2012-02-10. (I hope I got it right, I was surprised to find only 209 posts including tag wikis.)

<sup>Obtained through [SEDE](http://data.stackexchange.com/travel%20answers/query/97659/wikitravel-mentions-for-offline-postprocessing) and [Python](http://pastebin.com/Tkqsjt3c)</sup>

**A–L** (*continued in [M–Z](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1214/suggested-mandate-of-wikivoyage-links/1217#1217)*)

A seaside stroll in Helsinki ([travel](http://wikitravel.org/en/A_seaside_stroll_in_Helsinki), [voyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/A_seaside_stroll_in_Helsinki)) — [How many hours should I consider allowing to visit Suomenlinna and Seurasaari islands?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/8579/#8604)
Air travel in South Africa ([travel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Air_travel_in_South_Africa), [voyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Air_travel_in_South_Africa)) — [Cheapest season to go to South Africa from North America](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/7268/#7353)
Akihabara ([travel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Akihabara), [voyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Akihabara)) — [Where to buy a second-hand smartphone in Seoul?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/10158)
Americans in Cuba ([travel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Americans_in_Cuba), [voyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Americans_in_Cuba)) — [How can I find an ATM card usable in Cuba, by a US Citizen?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/11070) — [Is it advisable for US citizen to attempt a visit to Cuba w/o going through an agency?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/14/#40) — [Is it technically illegal for US citizens to visit Cuba?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/2684/#2694)
Andorra ([travel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Andorra), [voyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Andorra)) — https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/8294
Angel Falls ([travel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Angel_Falls), [voyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Angel_Falls)) — [How to get to Angel Falls?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/3034)
Angthong Marine National Park ([travel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Angthong_Marine_National_Park), [voyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Angthong_Marine_National_Park)) — [Any good scuba diving on Ko Samui, Thailand?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/11059/#11062)
Antwerp ([travel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Antwerp), [voyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Antwerp)) — [Must see places while going through Belgium?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/7553/#7560)
Astana ([travel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Astana), [voyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Astana)) — [[astana](https://travel.stackexchange.com/tags/astana/info)]
Athens ([travel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Athens), [voyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Athens)) — [How can I find train departure information for Athens - Istanbul?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/1629/#1630)
BaBth ([travel](http://wikitravel.org/en/BaBth), [voyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/BaBth)) — [Day trips from London?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/5317/#5344)
Banaue ([travel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Banaue), [voyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Banaue)) — [Is Clark (Philippines) worth a visit for 4 days](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/11003/#11078)
Bangkok ([travel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Bangkok), [voyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Bangkok)) — [Fastest way to get from Suvarnabhumi Airport to down town Bangkok in the early morning](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/10325) — [How to go from Bangkok airport to Khao San?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/7961/#7963) — [How to visit the floating market without an excursion in Bangkok?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/7973)
Barrow (Alaska) ([travel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Barrow_%28Alaska%29), [voyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Barrow_%28Alaska%29)) — [Getting to Barrow, Alaska overland](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/7798/#7810)
Bath ([travel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Bath), [voyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Bath)) — [Free parking in Bath UK](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/4302/#4358)
Batumi ([travel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Batumi), [voyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Batumi)) — [Which European cities have bike rental stations for tourists?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/250/#8043) — [Trains between Tbilisi and Batumi](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/7217/#7218)
Belgium ([travel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Belgium), [voyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Belgium)) — [[belgium](https://travel.stackexchange.com/tags/belgium/info)]
Beppu ([travel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Beppu), [voyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Beppu)) — [Getting around on Kyushu (Fukuoka, Nagasaki and Beppu)](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/4046/#4047)
Berlin ([travel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Berlin), [voyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Berlin)) — [[berlin](https://travel.stackexchange.com/tags/berlin/info)]
Bokhara ([travel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Bokhara), [voyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Bokhara)) — [Is there any accurate map for the Silk Route and is it still practicable?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/4033/#4040)
Bolaven Plateau ([travel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Bolaven_Plateau), [voyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Bolaven_Plateau)) — [Top destinations in Southern Laos and how to get there from Cambodia?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/3888/#3903)
Borobudur ([travel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Borobudur), [voyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Borobudur)) — [Where can someone see flowing lava at roughly Easter time?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/3924/#3928)
Brazil ([travel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Brazil), [voyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Brazil)) — [Proving onward travel on a South America tour](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/12779/#12806)
Bristol ([travel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Bristol), [voyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Bristol)) — [Day trips from London?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/5317/#5344)
Bruges ([travel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Bruges), [voyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Bruges)) — [Must see places while going through Belgium?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/7553/#7560)
Brussels ([travel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Brussels), [voyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Brussels)) — [Must see places while going through Belgium?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/7553/#7560)
Bulgaria ([travel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Bulgaria), [voyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Bulgaria)) — [In Bulgaria do fast food chains, convenience stores, or petrol stations typically accept credit cards for small purchases?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/1921/#1958)
Burnaby ([travel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Burnaby), [voyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Burnaby)) — [Hostel location in Vancouver](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/2437/#2447)
Bushehr ([travel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Bushehr), [voyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Bushehr)) — [Road journey from Europe to Mecca?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/9289/#9297)
Cambodia ([travel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Cambodia), [voyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Cambodia)) — [Does a Canadian need a visa to pass from Cambodia into Laos and then back?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/3887/#3889)
Cape Winelands ([travel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Cape_Winelands), [voyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Cape_Winelands)) — [Can I visit vineyards in Stellenbosch without booking a tour in advance?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/5871/#5878)
Chachoengsao ([travel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Chachoengsao), [voyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Chachoengsao)) — [Is there any interesting place to stop between Siem Reap and Bangkok?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/8299/#8304)
Champasak ([travel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Champasak), [voyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Champasak)) — [Top destinations in Southern Laos and how to get there from Cambodia?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/3888/#3903)
Chechnya ([travel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Chechnya), [voyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Chechnya)) — [Is it now feasible for an adventurous independent traveller to visit Chechnya?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/4163)
Chicago ([travel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Chicago), [voyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Chicago)) — [What are some old Irish neighbourhoods in Chicago?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/7170/#7174)
China ([travel](http://wikitravel.org/en/China), [voyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/China)) — [Are there any special considerations on a business trip to Shanghai?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/8616/#8617)
Christmas Island ([travel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Christmas_Island), [voyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Christmas_Island)) — [How to get to Christmas Island?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/4253)
Cinque Terre ([travel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Cinque_Terre), [voyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Cinque_Terre)) — [How to get from Genoa to Cinque Terre?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/10777)
City Center ([travel](http://wikitravel.org/en/City_Center), [voyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/City_Center)) — [Is this a realistic backpacking trip in Europe?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/3191/#3201)
Colosseo ([travel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Colosseo), [voyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Colosseo)) — [Is this a realistic backpacking trip in Europe?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/3191/#3201)
Copenhagen ([travel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Copenhagen), [voyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Copenhagen)) — [What are the best things to see in Copenhagen, Denmark?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/144/#182) — [How to get from Copenhagen airport to Tivoli](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/9642/#9643)
Crimea ([travel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Crimea), [voyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Crimea)) — [How to "speak" Russian, if you don't speak Russian?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/11728)
Cuba ([travel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Cuba), [voyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Cuba)) — [Crime rate in Cuba](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/3487/#3575) — [How do I get a tourist visa/card for Cuba?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/3764/#3767)
Dubai ([travel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Dubai), [voyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Dubai)) — [A day at Dubai International Airport and the city?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/5605/#5606)
Dublin ([travel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Dublin), [voyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Dublin)) — [[dublin](https://travel.stackexchange.com/tags/dublin/info)]
Essaouira ([travel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Essaouira), [voyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Essaouira)) — [Where can I ride camels in Morocco (other than in the Sahara)?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/5931/#5939)
Everest Base Camp Trek ([travel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Everest_Base_Camp_Trek), [voyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Everest_Base_Camp_Trek)) — [What is the actual price of hiring a porter for Everest base camp?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/2807)
Füssen ([travel](http://wikitravel.org/en/F%C3%BCssen), [voyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/F%C3%BCssen)) — https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/7902
Far Southwest Side ([travel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Far_Southwest_Side), [voyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Far_Southwest_Side)) — [What are some old Irish neighbourhoods in Chicago?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/7170/#7174)
Ferries in The Red Sea ([travel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Ferries_in_The_Red_Sea), [voyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Ferries_in_The_Red_Sea)) — [Road journey from Europe to Mecca?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/9289/#9297)
France ([travel](http://wikitravel.org/en/France), [voyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/France)) — [[france](https://travel.stackexchange.com/tags/france/info)]
Freighter travel ([travel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Freighter_travel), [voyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Freighter_travel)) — [Is there any possibility to ride on a freighter from Romania to South Korea?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/9047) — [What is the cheapest available freighter voyage anywhere?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/9048)
French Guiana ([travel](http://wikitravel.org/en/French_Guiana), [voyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/French_Guiana)) — [[french-guiana](https://travel.stackexchange.com/tags/french-guiana/info)]
Fukuoka (city) ([travel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Fukuoka_%28city%29), [voyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Fukuoka_%28city%29)) — [Getting around on Kyushu (Fukuoka, Nagasaki and Beppu)](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/4046/#4047)
Garden Route ([travel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Garden_Route), [voyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Garden_Route)) — [Itineraries in South Africa (+/- 2 Weeks)](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/2865/#2867)
Gdańsk ([travel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Gda%C5%84sk), [voyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Gda%C5%84sk)) — [[gdansk](https://travel.stackexchange.com/tags/gdansk/info)]
Georgia (country) ([travel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Georgia_%28country%29), [voyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Georgia_%28country%29)) — [Does the country Georgia have a problem with bears, wolves, or dangerous feral dogs?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/6595/#6823)
Ghent ([travel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Ghent), [voyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Ghent)) — [Must see places while going through Belgium?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/7553/#7560)
Gorkhi-Terelj National Park ([travel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Gorkhi-Terelj_National_Park), [voyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Gorkhi-Terelj_National_Park)) — [Getting to Terelj National Park from Ulaanbaatar, Mongolia](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/1559)
Grand Canyon ([travel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Grand_Canyon), [voyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Grand_Canyon)) — [View the Grand Canyon by helicopter - is it real?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/515/#6185)
Great Wall of China ([travel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Great_Wall_of_China), [voyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Great_Wall_of_China)) — [The Great Wall of China: Where should I start a visit?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/6405/#6406)
Greenland ([travel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Greenland), [voyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Greenland)) — [Can you actually do a road-trip in Greenland?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/7628/#7629)
Guatemala ([travel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Guatemala), [voyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Guatemala)) — [Is it possible to travel safely in Guatemala?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/4996/#4998)
Guayaquil ([travel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Guayaquil), [voyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Guayaquil)) — [How much is the airport tax at Guayaquil airport, Ecuador?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/11043/#11050) — [Is it cheaper to buy a tour to the Galápagos Islands at home or when in Ecuador?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/4133/#4349)
Guilin ([travel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Guilin), [voyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Guilin)) — [How should I prepare for a visit to the rice terraces?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/1606)
Ha Long Bay ([travel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Ha_Long_Bay), [voyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Ha_Long_Bay)) — [How to travel with a (small) child in Vietnam?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/2182/#2507)
Hawaii ([travel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Hawaii), [voyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Hawaii)) — [Is it possible to drive to Hawaii?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/8387/#8388)
Hebron ([travel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Hebron), [voyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Hebron)) — [Is it possible to visit Hebron and Mearat Hamachpela nowadays?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/8418/#8420)
Helsinki itineraries ([travel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Helsinki_itineraries), [voyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Helsinki_itineraries)) — [How many hours should I consider allowing to visit Suomenlinna and Seurasaari islands?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/8579/#8605)
Hitchhiking boats ([travel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Hitchhiking_boats), [voyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Hitchhiking_boats)) — [What is the cheapest available freighter voyage anywhere?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/9048/#9231)
Hong Kong ([travel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Hong_Kong), [voyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Hong_Kong)) — [[hong-kong](https://travel.stackexchange.com/tags/hong-kong/info)] — [Where can I eat a cobra (or any snake) in Hong Kong?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/6318/#6322)
Honolulu ([travel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Honolulu), [voyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Honolulu)) — [Getting from Honolulu to Mauna Kea](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/5896)
Image:Panorama of Malbork Castle.jpg ([travel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Image%3aPanorama_of_Malbork_Castle.jpg), [voyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Image%3aPanorama_of_Malbork_Castle.jpg)) — [How to visit Malbork Castle from Gdansk?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/5303)
Isla del Sol ([travel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Isla_del_Sol), [voyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Isla_del_Sol)) — [Boat tour on lake Titicaca?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/4227/#4233)
Italy ([travel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Italy), [voyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Italy)) — [Are there Italian customs that a North American should be aware of?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/381/#4475)
Japan ([travel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Japan), [voyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Japan)) — [How can I travel to Japan from mainland Asia by ship?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/3278/#3281) — [OK we're all nerds here, so really, how on earth should I use a Japanese toilet?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/5599/#5604)
Jeju ([travel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Jeju), [voyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Jeju)) — [Jeju Island (New Natural Wonder of the World) - How to Get There?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/3442/#3443)
Juarez ([travel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Juarez), [voyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Juarez)) — [How to travel safely in Ciudad Juárez, Mexico?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/7633/#7684)
Kalibo ([travel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Kalibo), [voyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Kalibo)) — [How to find car rental companies in Kalibo, Philippines?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/3931/#3932)
Kaliningrad ([travel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Kaliningrad), [voyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Kaliningrad)) — [Travel guide to Kaliningrad?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/5879/#5880)
Kaliningrad Oblast ([travel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Kaliningrad_Oblast), [voyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Kaliningrad_Oblast)) — [Is it difficult to do a car border crossing in Kaliningrad Oblast?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/4410)
Kangerlussuaq ([travel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Kangerlussuaq), [voyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Kangerlussuaq)) — [When and where do I have the highest chance of seeing auroras?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/145/#173)
Khao Sok National Park ([travel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Khao_Sok_National_Park), [voyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Khao_Sok_National_Park)) — [How should I travel from Khao Sok National Park to Ko Yao Noi in Thailand?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/4698/#4751)
Khiva ([travel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Khiva), [voyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Khiva)) — [Is there any accurate map for the Silk Route and is it still practicable?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/4033/#4040)
Ko Samui ([travel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Ko_Samui), [voyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Ko_Samui)) — [Any good scuba diving on Ko Samui, Thailand?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/11059/#11062)
Ko Tao ([travel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Ko_Tao), [voyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Ko_Tao)) — [Any good scuba diving on Ko Samui, Thailand?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/11059/#11062)
Ko Yao ([travel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Ko_Yao), [voyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Ko_Yao)) — [How should I travel from Khao Sok National Park to Ko Yao Noi in Thailand?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/4698/#4751)
Kobe ([travel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Kobe), [voyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Kobe)) — [How can I travel to Japan from mainland Asia by ship?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/3278/#3281)
Kopaonik ([travel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Kopaonik), [voyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Kopaonik)) — [What is the most interesting route from Sofia, Bulgaria to northern Albania?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/1961/#1988)
Krakow ([travel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Krakow), [voyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Krakow)) — [How to visit Wieliczka salt mines and the Auschwitz KZ from Krakow?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/5372/#5375)
Kuala Lumpur ([travel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Kuala_Lumpur), [voyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Kuala_Lumpur)) — [Best way to go from Sepang KLIA to downtown Kuala Lumpur?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/501) — [Best way to go from Sepang KLIA to downtown Kuala Lumpur?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/501/#513)
Kyushu ([travel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Kyushu), [voyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Kyushu)) — [Getting around on Kyushu (Fukuoka, Nagasaki and Beppu)](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/4046/#4047)
Lahore ([travel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Lahore), [voyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Lahore)) — [Getting 3rd party car insurance for Iran from Pakistan](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/1977/#1990)
Laos ([travel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Laos), [voyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Laos)) — [Does a Canadian need a visa to pass from Cambodia into Laos and then back?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/3887/#3889) — [Top destinations in Southern Laos and how to get there from Cambodia?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/3888/#3890) — [Travel from South East Asia to Europe by land](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/8638/#8649)
Lhasa ([travel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Lhasa), [voyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Lhasa)) — [Is it recommended to travel to Tibet (Lhasa) for just under 20 days and with a low budget?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/9726)
Lido ([travel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Lido), [voyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Lido)) — [Does it make more sense to stay in Lido or Venice?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/9160)
Liechtenstein ([travel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Liechtenstein), [voyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Liechtenstein)) — [[liechtenstein](https://travel.stackexchange.com/tags/liechtenstein/info)]
Lille ([travel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Lille), [voyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Lille)) — [[lille](https://travel.stackexchange.com/tags/lille/info)]
Lima ([travel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Lima), [voyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Lima)) — [Do I still have to pay airport fee in Lima?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/7635/#7638)
List Of Airline Baggage Limits ([travel](http://wikitravel.org/en/List_Of_Airline_Baggage_Limits), [voyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/List_Of_Airline_Baggage_Limits)) — [Checked baggage size limits](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/6024/#6025) — [Checked baggage size limits](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/6024/#6045)
Lithuania ([travel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Lithuania), [voyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Lithuania)) — [How to get to and from the Vilnius airport to old town in the early morning](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/7288/#7293)
London ([travel](http://wikitravel.org/en/London), [voyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/London)) — [[london](https://travel.stackexchange.com/tags/london/info)]
Lord Howe Island ([travel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Lord_Howe_Island), [voyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Lord_Howe_Island)) — [Possibility and price of getting to Lord Howe Island by sea?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/5847)

Answer (score -3):

<sup>***Please keep this answer's score at -2 so that it's displayed below the first part.***</sup>

**M–Z** *(continued from [A-L](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1214/suggested-mandate-of-wikivoyage-links/1216#1216))*

Machu Picchu ([travel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Machu_Picchu), [voyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Machu_Picchu)) — [Can anyone recommend a good trekking tour for Machu Picchu?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/378)
Madrid ([travel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Madrid), [voyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Madrid)) — [[madrid](https://travel.stackexchange.com/tags/madrid/info)]
Main Page ([travel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Main_Page), [voyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Main_Page)) — [How to systematically find a place to go to for newbies](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/6850/#6860) — [Unique travel destination research methods](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/8395/#8396)
Mangalia ([travel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Mangalia), [voyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Mangalia)) — [Are there any places that serve Korean food in Doi Mai or Mangalia in Romania?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/9042)
Marrakech ([travel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Marrakech), [voyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Marrakech)) — [What are the operational times for public transport in Marrakech, and where can I find a schedule?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/4422)
Mauritius ([travel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Mauritius), [voyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Mauritius)) — [What kind of questions should I be asking about tropical destinations?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/34/#76)
Mechelen ([travel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Mechelen), [voyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Mechelen)) — [Must see places while going through Belgium?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/7553/#7560)
Meditation in Japan ([travel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Meditation_in_Japan), [voyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Meditation_in_Japan)) — [Health retreats in Japan](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/5363/#5530)
Merzouga ([travel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Merzouga), [voyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Merzouga)) — [Where can I ride camels in Morocco (other than in the Sahara)?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/5931/#5958)
Mexico ([travel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Mexico), [voyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Mexico)) — [What are the fake police checkpoints in Mexico looking for?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/4668/#4669)
Monaco ([travel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Monaco), [voyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Monaco)) — [[monaco](https://travel.stackexchange.com/tags/monaco/info)] — [Visiting Monaco as an EU citizen -- what to think about?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/7298/#7305)
Mongolia ([travel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Mongolia), [voyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Mongolia)) — [[mongolia](https://travel.stackexchange.com/tags/mongolia/info)]
Mont Saint Michel ([travel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Mont_Saint_Michel), [voyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Mont_Saint_Michel)) — [What's the nearest train station to Mont Saint-Michel?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/7984/#7988) — [What's the nearest train station to Mont Saint-Michel?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/7984/#7995)
Montana ([travel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Montana), [voyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Montana)) — [What are my options for transportation around the Great Plains (US)?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/3209/#13215)
Montezuma ([travel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Montezuma), [voyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Montezuma)) — [Need information on traveling to Montezuma, CR and Panama](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/11364/#11421)
Morocco ([travel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Morocco), [voyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Morocco)) — [[morocco](https://travel.stackexchange.com/tags/morocco/info)] — [Is it safe to drink tap water in Morocco?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/4421) — [What are the rules surounding alcohol in Morocco](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/4443/#4445)
Mount Merapi ([travel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Mount_Merapi), [voyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Mount_Merapi)) — [Where can someone see flowing lava at roughly Easter time?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/3924/#3928)
Myanmar ([travel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Myanmar), [voyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Myanmar)) — [Are there still parts of Burma that are off-limits to tourists?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/12746/#12760) — [Is it possible to travel through Burma (Myanmar), entering at one border crossing and exiting at another?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/291/#3641) — [Is it possible to travel through Burma (Myanmar), entering at one border crossing and exiting at another?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/291/#712) — [Travel from South East Asia to Europe by land](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/8638/#8649)
Nagasaki (city) ([travel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Nagasaki_%28city%29), [voyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Nagasaki_%28city%29)) — [Getting around on Kyushu (Fukuoka, Nagasaki and Beppu)](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/4046/#4047)
Netherlands ([travel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Netherlands), [voyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Netherlands)) — [[netherlands](https://travel.stackexchange.com/tags/netherlands/info)]
New Caledonia ([travel](http://wikitravel.org/en/New_Caledonia), [voyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/New_Caledonia)) — [How widely spoken is English in New Caledonia (Nouvelle-Calédonie)?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/11553/#11555)
New Orleans ([travel](http://wikitravel.org/en/New_Orleans), [voyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/New_Orleans)) — [New Orleans Live Music Venue Recommendations](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/4817/#5127) — [New Orleans ... With kids?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/5450/#5452)
New York City ([travel](http://wikitravel.org/en/New_York_City), [voyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/New_York_City)) — [Connecting time at JFK](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/2265/#2311)
Ninh Binh ([travel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Ninh_Binh), [voyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Ninh_Binh)) — [Can anyone recommend the most interesting 2 or 3 day cycle in Vietnam?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/3622/#3647)
Noel Kempff Mercado National Park ([travel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Noel_Kempff_Mercado_National_Park), [voyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Noel_Kempff_Mercado_National_Park)) — [Camping in Noel Kempff Mercado National Park in Bolivia](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/4216)
North Korea ([travel](http://wikitravel.org/en/North_Korea), [voyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/North_Korea)) — [Can I travel to North Korea overland (via train)?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/4152/#4154)
Northern Armenia ([travel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Northern_Armenia), [voyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Northern_Armenia)) — [Where is this half buried Armenian church or monastery?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/3387/#3388)
Norway ([travel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Norway), [voyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Norway)) — [Is Norway significantly more expensive than other European destinations?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/1374/#1910)
Nuuk ([travel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Nuuk), [voyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Nuuk)) — [How to get from Iceland to Greenland?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/4734/#4753)
Off the beaten track in Japan ([travel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Off_the_beaten_track_in_Japan), [voyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Off_the_beaten_track_in_Japan)) — [Is there a guide regarding places least known/visited in Japan?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/7673/#7675)
Okinawa ([travel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Okinawa), [voyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Okinawa)) — [How, specifically, can I travel between Taiwan and Okinawa by sea?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/11567/#11575)
Olympic area ([travel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Olympic_area), [voyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Olympic_area)) — [Is this a realistic backpacking trip in Europe?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/3191/#3201)
Osaka ([travel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Osaka), [voyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Osaka)) — [How can I travel to Japan from mainland Asia by ship?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/3278/#3281)
Ouarzazate ([travel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Ouarzazate), [voyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Ouarzazate)) — [Where can I ride camels in Morocco (other than in the Sahara)?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/5931/#5958)
Oudtshoorn ([travel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Oudtshoorn), [voyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Oudtshoorn)) — [Itineraries in South Africa (+/- 2 Weeks)](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/2865/#2867)
Pärnu ([travel](http://wikitravel.org/en/P%C3%A4rnu), [voyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/P%C3%A4rnu)) — [Backpacking in Pärnu in the summer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/8282)
Page ([travel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Page), [voyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Page)) — [Getting to Horseshoe Bend, Arizona?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/6837)
Pakse ([travel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Pakse), [voyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Pakse)) — [Top destinations in Southern Laos and how to get there from Cambodia?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/3888/#3903)
Palau ([travel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Palau), [voyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Palau)) — [How could I explore the Rock Islands of Palau?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/1308/#1313)
Paris ([travel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Paris), [voyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Paris)) — [[paris](https://travel.stackexchange.com/tags/paris/info)]
Perhentian Islands ([travel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Perhentian_Islands), [voyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Perhentian_Islands)) — [Eco touring/diving in Malaysia](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/155/#179)
Periyar National Park ([travel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Periyar_National_Park), [voyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Periyar_National_Park)) — [Where in India can one wash and play with elephants?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/5268/#5270)
Peru ([travel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Peru), [voyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Peru)) — [Local cuisine in Peru](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/4967/#4968)
Phillip Island ([travel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Phillip_Island), [voyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Phillip_Island)) — [Seeing Penguins "in the wild" in Sydney](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/6416/#6418)
Plovdiv ([travel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Plovdiv), [voyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Plovdiv)) — [Buses from Plovdiv, Bulgaria to Istanbul, Turkey](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/1912/#3633)
Poipet ([travel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Poipet), [voyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Poipet)) — [Is there any interesting place to stop between Siem Reap and Bangkok?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/8299/#8304)
Port Douglas ([travel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Port_Douglas), [voyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Port_Douglas)) — [Is there public transport in and around Cairns, Australia out of regular hours?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/9759/#9766)
Portsmouth ([travel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Portsmouth), [voyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Portsmouth)) — [Day trips from London?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/5317/#5344)
Prambanan ([travel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Prambanan), [voyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Prambanan)) — [Where can someone see flowing lava at roughly Easter time?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/3924/#3928)
Pudong ([travel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Pudong), [voyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Pudong)) — [How can I get a great view of Shanghai?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/1634/#1635)
Puno ([travel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Puno), [voyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Puno)) — [Boat tour on lake Titicaca?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/4227/#4231) — [Boat tour on lake Titicaca?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/4227/#4237)
Puntarenas ([travel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Puntarenas), [voyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Puntarenas)) — [Need information on traveling to Montezuma, CR and Panama](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/11364/#11421)
Qatar ([travel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Qatar), [voyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Qatar)) — [Qatar - "stranded" for 8 hours](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/10837/#10848) — [What should I do/visit in Qatar for 8 hours?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/3586/#3587)
Qingdao ([travel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Qingdao), [voyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Qingdao)) — [How can I travel to Japan from mainland Asia by ship?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/3278/#3281)
Queen Anne-South Lake Union ([travel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Queen_Anne-South_Lake_Union), [voyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Queen_Anne-South_Lake_Union)) — [Time needed to visit the Seattle Space Needle](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/1057/#4306)
Rail travel in Europe ([travel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Rail_travel_in_Europe), [voyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Rail_travel_in_Europe)) — [Traveling from Anaklia Georgia to Greece?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/6774/#6777)
Renting a car ([travel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Renting_a_car), [voyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Renting_a_car)) — [Are there any legal requirements for renting a car in the US as a foreigner?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/4901/#4906)
Rio de Janeiro ([travel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Rio_de_Janeiro), [voyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Rio_de_Janeiro)) — [Is there public transport running on NYE in Rio de Janeiro?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/4244/#4353)
Rocamadour ([travel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Rocamadour), [voyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Rocamadour)) — [Visiting Rocamadour, France by train](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/7981/#8017)
Romania ([travel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Romania), [voyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Romania)) — [Safely driving a car in Romania with foreign plates](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/5750/#5770)
Rome ([travel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Rome), [voyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Rome)) — [Where are the shopping areas in Rome?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/6258/#6271)
Rovaniemi ([travel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Rovaniemi), [voyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Rovaniemi)) — [When and where do I have the highest chance of seeing auroras?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/145/#173)
Rurrenabaque ([travel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Rurrenabaque), [voyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Rurrenabaque)) — [5 weeks in Peru + Bolivia + Chile, is too little time?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/11145/#11168)
Safed ([travel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Safed), [voyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Safed)) — [Itinerary for Galilee and the Golan](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/1552)
Saint Martin ([travel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Saint_Martin), [voyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Saint_Martin)) — [Avoiding tourist traps while still having fun in Sint Maarten](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/4828/#4970) — https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/4833
Samarkand ([travel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Samarkand), [voyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Samarkand)) — [Is there any accurate map for the Silk Route and is it still practicable?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/4033/#4040)
San Blas Islands ([travel](http://wikitravel.org/en/San_Blas_Islands), [voyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/San_Blas_Islands)) — [Suitable ways to get around the Darién Gap?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/93/#347)
San Diego ([travel](http://wikitravel.org/en/San_Diego), [voyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/San_Diego)) — [Getting from San Diego airport to near the Convention Centre without a car?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/2243/#2245)
Sanya ([travel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Sanya), [voyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Sanya)) — [Airport transfer in Sanya](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/1265/#1816)
Sao Tome and Principe ([travel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Sao_Tome_and_Principe), [voyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Sao_Tome_and_Principe)) — [How to get to São Tomé and Príncipe?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/8297/#8308)
Sarajevo ([travel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Sarajevo), [voyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Sarajevo)) — [Getting from Bosnia to Kosovo](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/8257/#8264)
Saudi Arabia ([travel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Saudi_Arabia), [voyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Saudi_Arabia)) — [The most difficult countries to travel in?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/5809/#5812)
Savannakhet ([travel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Savannakhet), [voyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Savannakhet)) — [Top destinations in Southern Laos and how to get there from Cambodia?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/3888/#3903)
Scotland ([travel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Scotland), [voyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Scotland)) — [[scotland](https://travel.stackexchange.com/tags/scotland/info)]
Senegal ([travel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Senegal), [voyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Senegal)) — [Where lies the closest tropical rain forest to Mainland Europe?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/7067/#7074)
Seoul ([travel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Seoul), [voyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Seoul)) — [What time does the Seoul subway system open in the morning?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/10148)
Serbia ([travel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Serbia), [voyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Serbia)) — [What foreign language is the most common in Serbia?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/7607/#7608)
Shanghai ([travel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Shanghai), [voyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Shanghai)) — [Which Shanghai airport is convenient for city center? Hongqiao or Pudong?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/10170) — [How can I travel to Japan from mainland Asia by ship?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/3278/#3281)
Shanhaiguan ([travel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Shanhaiguan), [voyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Shanhaiguan)) — [The Great Wall of China: Where should I start a visit?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/6405/#6406)
Sharjah ([travel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Sharjah), [voyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Sharjah)) — [Will I get in trouble if I drink beer in public in Dubai?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/3410/#3413)
Sheki ([travel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Sheki), [voyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Sheki)) — [How to get from Sheki to Tbilisi](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/7287/#7291)
Shenmu ([travel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Shenmu), [voyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Shenmu)) — [The Great Wall of China: Where should I start a visit?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/6405/#6406)
Shimonoseki ([travel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Shimonoseki), [voyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Shimonoseki)) — [How can I travel to Japan from mainland Asia by ship?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/3278/#3281)
Si Phan Don ([travel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Si_Phan_Don), [voyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Si_Phan_Don)) — [Recommended destinations located close to Siem Reap, Cambodia](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/1060/#1062) — [Top destinations in Southern Laos and how to get there from Cambodia?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/3888/#3903)
Siem Reap ([travel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Siem_Reap), [voyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Siem_Reap)) — [How to get to Siem Reap (Angkor Wat) from Pakse by land?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/8289)
Silk Road ([travel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Silk_Road), [voyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Silk_Road)) — [Is there any accurate map for the Silk Route and is it still practicable?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/4033/#4040) — [Travel from South East Asia to Europe by land](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/8638/#8649)
Sisophon ([travel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Sisophon), [voyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Sisophon)) — [Is there any interesting place to stop between Siem Reap and Bangkok?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/8299/#8304)
Socotra ([travel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Socotra), [voyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Socotra)) — [Is it safe to travel to Socotra, Yemen?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/136/#4477)
South Iceland ([travel](http://wikitravel.org/en/South_Iceland), [voyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/South_Iceland)) — [Information about Fimmvörðuháls route](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/7143/#7232)
Stockholm ([travel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Stockholm), [voyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Stockholm)) — [Why is Nynäshamn a de facto "port" for Stockholm?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/3239/#3245)
Stung Treng ([travel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Stung_Treng), [voyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Stung_Treng)) — [Does a Canadian need a visa to pass from Cambodia into Laos and then back?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/3887/#3899)
Sudbury (Ontario) ([travel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Sudbury_%28Ontario%29), [voyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Sudbury_%28Ontario%29)) — [Is the Sudbury Slag Pour still a thing?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/13198)
Suzhou ([travel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Suzhou), [voyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Suzhou)) — [How can I travel to Japan from mainland Asia by ship?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/3278/#3281)
Switzerland ([travel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Switzerland), [voyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Switzerland)) — [[switzerland](https://travel.stackexchange.com/tags/switzerland/info)] — [How important is it to obtain Swiss Francs before arriving in Switzerland?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/6321/#6323)
Sydney ([travel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Sydney), [voyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Sydney)) — [Layover in Sydney on NZ Passport - can I leave the airport?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/11091/#11092)
Taipei ([travel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Taipei), [voyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Taipei)) — [Internet connections in Taipei](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/7770)
Tallinn ([travel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Tallinn), [voyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Tallinn)) — [From Tallinn harbour to the main bus station](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/8340/#8341) — [From Tallinn harbour to the main bus station](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/8340/#8342)
Tbilisi ([travel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Tbilisi), [voyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Tbilisi)) — [Which route did the old Tbilisi-Rostov train route take and is it closed only for political reasons?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/2069/#2072) — [Are there ticket offices for Georgian Railways in Tbilisi?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/8032)
Thalkirchen ([travel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Thalkirchen), [voyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Thalkirchen)) — [Is this a realistic backpacking trip in Europe?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/3191/#3201)
Tianjin ([travel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Tianjin), [voyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Tianjin)) — [How can I travel to Japan from mainland Asia by ship?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/3278/#3281)
Tiberias ([travel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Tiberias), [voyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Tiberias)) — [Itinerary for Galilee and the Golan](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/1552)
Timbuktu ([travel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Timbuktu), [voyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Timbuktu)) — [From Here to Timbuktu - how do I get there?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/7135)
Toyama ([travel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Toyama), [voyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Toyama)) — [Are there any ferry companies operating between Russian East ports and Japan?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/802/#803)
Transkei ([travel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Transkei), [voyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Transkei)) — [Itineraries in South Africa (+/- 2 Weeks)](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/2865/#2867)
Tromso ([travel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Tromso), [voyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Tromso)) — [Tromsø for the Aurora Borealis in March](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/3738/#3743)
Udaipur ([travel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Udaipur), [voyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Udaipur)) — [Transfer to Udaipur airport](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/6137/#6141)
Uluru-Kata Tjuta National Park ([travel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Uluru-Kata_Tjuta_National_Park), [voyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Uluru-Kata_Tjuta_National_Park)) — [Is it possible to climb Uluru (Ayers Rock)?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/3573/#3574)
Uros Islands ([travel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Uros_Islands), [voyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Uros_Islands)) — [Boat tour on lake Titicaca?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/4227/#4237)
Vang Vieng ([travel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Vang_Vieng), [voyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Vang_Vieng)) — [Is there still tubing going on in Vang Vieng, Laos?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/10367/#10431)
Vatican ([travel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Vatican), [voyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Vatican)) — [Is this a realistic backpacking trip in Europe?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/3191/#3201)
Venice ([travel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Venice), [voyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Venice)) — [[venice](https://travel.stackexchange.com/tags/venice/info)]
Vienna ([travel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Vienna), [voyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Vienna)) — [[vienna](https://travel.stackexchange.com/tags/vienna/info)]
Vilcabamba ([travel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Vilcabamba), [voyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Vilcabamba)) — [Which border crossing should I take between Ecuador and Peru](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/4161/#4334)
West Bali National Park ([travel](http://wikitravel.org/en/West_Bali_National_Park), [voyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/West_Bali_National_Park)) — [Travel without a purpose to Bali](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/10836/#10850)
West End ([travel](http://wikitravel.org/en/West_End), [voyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/West_End)) — [Can tourists visit the White House or the US Capitol Building?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/11307/#11315)
Windsor and Eton ([travel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Windsor_and_Eton), [voyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Windsor_and_Eton)) — [Day trips from London?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/5317/#5344)
Wrocław ([travel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Wroc%C5%82aw), [voyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Wroc%C5%82aw)) — [How to get from Wroclaw airport to the main train station?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/9082/#9083)
Wroclaw ([travel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Wroclaw), [voyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Wroclaw)) — [How to get from Wroclaw airport to city center?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/5175/#5177)
Yala National Park ([travel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Yala_National_Park), [voyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Yala_National_Park)) — [Camping in national parks in Sri Lanka](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/3308/#3313) — [Camping in national parks in Sri Lanka](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/3308/#3314)
Yogyakarta ([travel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Yogyakarta), [voyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Yogyakarta)) — [Where can someone see flowing lava at roughly Easter time?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/3924/#3928)
Yongsan ([travel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Yongsan), [voyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Yongsan)) — [Where to buy a second-hand smartphone in Seoul?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/10158)
Yulin ([travel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Yulin), [voyage](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Yulin))